# How to adapt the week-month break point in a vis timeline

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

Is there a way to specify the "breakpoint" (according to css media queries) at which the display scale is toggled from weeks to month or vice versa?
I'd like to display up to 53 weeks. Currently the scale is changed from week to month when displaying more than 35+ weeks.
(Btw.: Setting a fixed scale is not an option.)

Comment: you may have better luck asking in the vis.js github project: https://github.com/visjs/vis-timeline/issues good luck!

Comment: that was my first thought. but github recommends stackoverflow for usage questions.